# How to allow automatic update of a pie chart in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to automatically update pie chart (from MVC) when an user inserts new data into the system?

Comment: Yea we're going to need to see your code

Comment: Assuming this is some sort of js chart either refresh periodically or use something like SignalR. May want to make some effort with your question if you want answers. What have you tried....

Comment: @Daniel since you practically answered your own question there nothing much to add but for automatic update on new data insert you need to send __push notifications__ to your client or use __polling__ to check for new data.

Answer (score 0):

Use SignalR since you are ASP.NET. It simplifies the process of adding real-time web functionality to applications. If you need more information, visit http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr